# Doctrine/symfony: getSqlQuery() output in phpMyAdmin/SQL tab

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

i have created this query that works OK:

```
$q1 = Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->from('Usuario u')
     ->leftJoin('u.AmigoUsuario a ON u.id = a.user2_id OR u.id = a.user1_id')
     ->where("a.user2_id = ? OR a.user1_id = ?", array($id,$id))
     ->andWhere("u.id <> ?", $id)
     ->andWhere("a.estado LIKE ?", 1);

echo $q1->getSqlQuery();
```

The calling to getSqlQuery outputs this clause:

> SELECT s.id AS s__id, s.username AS
> s__username, s.algorithm AS
> s__algorithm, s.salt AS s__salt,
> s.password AS s__password, s.is_active
> AS s__is_active, s.is_super_admin AS
> s__is_super_admin, s.last_login AS
> s__last_login, s.email_address AS
> s__email_address, s.nombre_apellidos
> AS s__nombre_apellidos, s.sexo AS
> s__sexo, s.fecha_nac AS s__fecha_nac,
> s.provincia AS s__provincia,
> s.localidad AS s__localidad,
> s.fotografia AS s__fotografia,
> s.avatar AS s__avatar,
> s.avatar_mensajes AS
> s__avatar_mensajes, s.created_at AS
> s__created_at, s.updated_at AS
> s__updated_at, a.id AS a__id,
> a.user1_id AS a__user1_id, a.user2_id
> AS a__user2_id, a.estado AS a__estado
> FROM sf_guard_user s LEFT JOIN
> amigo_usuario a ON ((s.id = a.user2_id
> OR s.id = a.user1_id)) WHERE
> ((a.user2_id = ? OR a.user1_id = ?)
> AND s.id <> ? AND a.estado LIKE ?)

If i take that clause to phpmyadmin SQL tab i get this error

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? OR a.user1_id = ?) AND s.id <> ? AND a.estado LIKE ?) LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Why i'm getting this error?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output includes placeholders in the query rather than actual values.  You need to replace the `?`'s with the correct values when you execute this in phpMyAdmin.

Using Symfony in dev mode, the values you're using for each query are shown in the database query panel accessible from the dev mode toolbar top right of your page, enclosed in parentheses after the query itself.